# How to check if Nvidia Optimus drivers are install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I have an Nvidia Geforce 640m Card.

I installed the bumblebee PPA follow the instructions from the original website. I rebooted but how do I check if the drivers were installed?

I run glxgears and optirun with it and both of them yielded the same results.

I tried installing the Bumblebee GUI but it's not showing up after I boot.

Also, are there supposed to be any changes in the "Graphics" section in the "About this Computer"?

It's currently only showing Driver :Intel® Ivybridge Mobile  Experience: Standard.

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command,

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
```

If the output of the above code shows `nvidia xxx` then it was confirmed that you had installed nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thank you. It shows that bumblebee nvidia as well as nvidia 304 are installed!
Just wondering though, do all these drivers run automatically, or do I have to run a certain code every time I want to run it? Like the optirun command?